# Having HTML markup as part JSON response, is it a best practice?

Tags: html, json, api, http

Is it a good practice to have html markup as part of API response? which has the content-type as `application/json`

Sample json response

`{
    html : '<div id="markup">This is the server response html.</div>',
    data : {property : 'This is the data received from the server.'}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not best practice.

Generally, you want to create a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) within your systems. By having your API return HTML, your server starts to take some responsibility for the presentation layer of your application as well as providing the data.

Think about what would happen if in future, you want to build a mobile app using your server. It wouldn't be able to effectively make use of the `html` property. Would you add a separate property that gets used by the mobile app? You don't want to keep changing your API server each time a new client wants to use it.

Think about what happens if you get a designer on to help you with your application. They now need the ability to modify code on the API server as well as the web layer. If you keep presentation of the data separate to the raw data, you won't run into this problem.